# How to host ASP.Net webservice over the internet

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, web-services

I have my `webservice` to serve as a connection between `C# windows` form and `MYSQL database`. So I'm thinking is there step by step method on how to make my `webservice` run not only in `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

This link will do your work-
[Deploying ASP.NET Websites on IIS 7.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS)